# Same code, works in runserver but not in apache

Tags: python, django, apache

views.py

```
def create_reply(request, topic_id):
if request.method == 'POST':

    t = topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    past_time = int(time.time() - t.locktime)

    r = post()

    r.topic = t
    if request.POST['content']:
        r.content = request.POST['content']
    else:
        return error(request, '不能空着')
        # messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, _('content cannot be empty'))
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('topic_view', kwargs={'topic_id': topic_id}))
    if past_time > 300:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, _('overtime'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('topic_view', kwargs={'topic_id': topic_id}))

    r.user = request.user
    # when success to reply ,unlock the topic.
    t.locker = '0'
    t.locked = False
    t.last_replier = request.user.username
    r.floor = t.reply_count + 1
    r.keyword = t.keyword
    if t.keyword ==  "keywordwrite":
        t.keyword = rand_key()
    elif t.keyword == "freewrite":
        t.keyword = None

    user_has_subscribed = t.subscriber.filter(
        username=request.user.username
    )

    if not user_has_subscribed:
        t.subscriber.add(request.user)
    t.save()
    r.save()
    sendemail.after_response(t.subscriber.all(),t)
    sendemail(t.subscriber.all(), t)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('topic_view', kwargs={'topic_id': t.id}))
elif request.method == 'GET':
    return error(request, 'don\'t get')
```

sendemail is

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
import after_response

@after_response.enable
def sendemail(users_list,topic):
    def get_mail_list(users_list):
        def getmail(user):
            return user.email
        mail_list = map(getmail,users_list)
        return mail_list
    link ='http://www.gushijielong.cn/topic/'+str(topic.id)
    mail_list=get_mail_list(users_list)
    mailtitle =u'你关注的主题：'+ topic.title + u'有新的接续了'
    mailcontent = u'点击查看'+ topic.title + u'的新接续' + "<a href='" + link + u"'>点击</a>"
    email = EmailMessage(mailtitle, mailcontent, to=mail_list)
    email.content_subtype = "html"
    print mailcontent
    email.send()
```

This code is for sending email to the subscribers when a topic has a new reply.
It **works( I can receive the emails )** in runserver, but not in apache.
sendemail() works well when I excute it in the server's console.

Comment: what do you mean, "it doesnt work"? what error are you getting?

Comment: @ritlew I can not receive the email sent from my website. And no error I've got which makes me even confused.

Comment: can you confirm that the function is being called at all?

Comment: @ritlew I think yes it was being called since it is placed right before the response, and the page is rendered successfully.

Comment: what are the server email settings? sometimes people only have the server settings set to debug

Comment: @ritlew settings may be fine, because I can send emails by executing  'send_mail()' on server console.